# Как вызвать autocomplete из php?

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, php, javascript

Всем доброго дня.

Наткнулся на полезный [компонентик](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete).

Там снизу дан пример использования из html.
В примере в javascript жестко прописан массив строк. Я буду это строить из php.

Интересует два вопроса:

1. Как созданный в php массив передать в этот javascript параметром?
2. Как при выборе нужной строки перезапистить скрипт с нужными значениями? (Т.е. если я рядом делаю кнопку, могу сделать, чтобы после выбора и нажатия на кнопку производились нужные действия, но кнопка в данном случае лишняя, куда тогда встроить функционал?)

Comment: Можно и в JSON-файлик кидать, но что мешает забирать сразу из обработчика?  
PHP не скидывает ничего, а ждёт когда постучится клиент, чтобы забрать накопленное - туда и скидывать результат.

Comment: @Isaev, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @TheDoctor, "но что мешает забирать сразу из обработчика"

Если это тот же php, он запустится ещё раз при выполнении post, потому это отдельный php, как я понял.

В основном скрипте выполняется поиск из большой базы скриптов, потом парсинг скрипта, потом деобфускация, и всё это занимает определенное время... Для чего тот же самый функционал встраивать во второй скрипт и запускать тот же процесс повторно, для получения массива, который готов в основном скрипте?

Или всё проще?

Comment: Я понятия не имею, как проще, т.к. я не знаком с твоим скриптом.  
Делай как тебе удобнее.

Answer (score 1):

1. Передать можно разными способами - от банального вписывания в код страницы до получения объекта типа JSON, который можно распарсить в массив.
2. Второе не очень понял, нужно какое-либо действие для выбора следующих шагов. :)
   Клик по кнопке - один из них. Можно вешать обработчик на `keyup/keypress/keydown`, можно на `change` или `focus` - вариантов куча, всё зависит от твоей задумки пользовательского интерфейса.

Comment: 1. Т.е. если я в php имею массив $arr, я его не могу передать в функцию? Переделать в объект типа JSON я могу, а что с ним дальше делать?

2. Это я, наверное, разберусь, на select там вроде вешается...

С первым проблема... Банально вписать может и вариант, не особо нравится только он мне, ибо страницы будут тяжелые. Сделать отдельный скрипт, который будет возвращать json и его брать как source? И почему js не может нормально взаимодействовать с php)

Comment: Не понимаю, в чём проблема, если не хочешь вшивать напрямую (и правильно, что не хочешь), то нужно передавать неявно.  
Когда-то была проблема общения, и стояла она весьма остро. Для решения придумали JSON, он получился настолько хорош, что его использует практически любой язык.  
Тебе нужно только запросит массив в виде JSON, распарсить его функцией `JSON.parse(array)` и вставить этот массив куда надо.

Comment: // file.php
$array = [
 'PHP',
 'JS',
 'AC',
 'Perl'
];
print json_encode($array);

// file.js
$.post('', function(data){ // jQuery чтобы не расписывать код на нативном JS
 myAutoupdateVar = JSON.parse(data);
});

Comment: @TheDoctor, проблема, видимо, в том, что всегда обходился без js. )
В примере по ссылке не нашёл явного вызова функции, потому не понял, как ей вообще можно параметры передать.

Жёстко прописал пока так:

     echo   '["'.implode('","', array_slice($navNtmp, 1)).'"];';

Работает, но интересено с вашим примером разобраться.

    $.post('', function(data){...});

Тут data откуда и как берётся?

Comment: Ууу, батенька, идите учить хотя бы основы JS.  
Тут [callback-function](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28программирование%29) получает как аргумент результат запроса.  
Т.е. после выполнения запроса и получения ответа, выполнится функция `function(data){/* some code here... */}`, результат запроса будет в переменной `data`.  
Кстати, называть можешь как угодно, хоть `mySuperPuperVariable`, но это длинно и неинформативно, лучше сразу называть как нужно - себе же работы меньше будет.

Comment: каюсь, основы то конечно нужно... если эта тема затянет или будет острая необходимость. пока просто приклеить пример к проекту нужно)

А, ответ во второй переменной! Я просто по аналогии с другими языками, выглядит странно... обычно post("куда", "параметры") тут получается запрос пустой '', в параметрах к пустому запросу данные, которые мы парсим из json которого нет.

И всё равно, почему пустой запрос? там 'file.php' наверное?

Comment: `$.post()` не пуст, там URI, я его не написал, т.к. не знаю пути.  
На самом деле это функция библиотеки jQuery, которую я не люблю, но на нативном делать асинхронный запрос чуть дольше, поэтому написал для краткости.  
Выглядит примерно так:

    $.post('/path_to_my_script_with_array.php', function(e){
     
    });

Comment: Сама функция `$.post()`, в свою очередь, является обёрткой `$.ajax()` - вот главная функция библиотеки.  
[Почитаешь мне ману, папа-гугл?](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax_запрос_методом_POST)

Comment: Всё же придётся делать через промежуточный файл, наверное... Тот же JSON в него буду скидывать, а из js забирать иначе долго получается, 2 раза одно и то же считать. Благодарствую за полезные примерчики.